# Improving clarity of images in PictureBox C#

Tags: c#, graphics, drawing

I have Panel on windows form containing labels for displaying information and 2 PictureBox controls. One for Company logo & other for captured photo. When i print them either on Printer or just save in PDF format, both images looking very blur. I want to improve quality of images. So they will appear clear even after zoom. 
Any suggestion.

Comment: Your images are probably way too small. You may need two versions, one for ca 72-102 dpi screen display and one for 150-600 dpi printing..

Comment: Can anyone tell me what is the best way to display and print company logo in C# win form? Container may be anything. 
Currently I am working with vector format images (.svg, .eps etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can set this [property](http://question.ikende.com/question/2D363731303631393131) of the Graphics object.

// g is type of Graphics.

```
g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;
```

Comment: tried with InterpolationMode, but no effect. eg - e.Graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.High;

Comment: Can anyone tell me what is the best way to display and print company logo in C# win form? Container may be anything. 
Currently I am working with vector format images (.svg, .eps etc)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which technique you are using for printing but if you are using print form it is not good for decent picture or text. Therefore when you send form/PictureBox to the print object it would lose quality.The Solution is to use PrintDocument.

Share your code for more help.

Comment: I am using PrintDocument  
PrintDocument doc = new PrintDocument();
doc.PrintPage += this.Doc_PrintPage;
doc.Print();

private void Doc_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
{
 float x = 209, y = 8;
 Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(this.panel2.Width, this.panel2.Height);
 this.panel2.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0,   this.panel2.Width+2, this.panel2.Height+2));
 e.Graphics.DrawImage((Image)bmp, x, y);
}

Answer (score 0):

Your printer has better resolution than your monitor. That bitmap won't work. You will have to recreate the print items directly on the e.Graphics of the PrintPageEventArgs.

Other work around is the technique that guy explain in his article.

http://www.dahuatu.com/3vy2K5z5mr.html